# Infinetly many primes of form $4k+3$

Tags: problem-solving

Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k + 3$ (where $k$ is an integer).

Note that it is a special case of
"Theorem 6 (Dirichlet). Let a and b be positive coprime integers. Then the sequence
$b$, $b + a$, $b + 2a$, $b + 3a$, $b + 4a$, $b + 5a$, ....,"
contains infinitely many prime numbers

So far I got that suppose there are a finite number of primes

$p......p$  and if $4(p.....p)+3$ is prime it's a contradiction so the initial statement is proven?

Comment: But what if it's not prime?

Comment: You need to prove more. Note that $4p_1\cdots p_n+3$ is not necessarily prime, but it **is** divisible by a prime different from the $p_i$ and of the form $4k+3$. You need to show that part too. Not hard.

Answer (score 0):

We know there are infinite odd primes.

Suppose there are not. Then there is a finite set $A$ which contains all primes of the form $4k+3$. Let P be  the product of all of those primes.

If $|A|$ is odd then $P+4$ is of the form $4k+3$ and is not divisible by any of the elements of $A$ but it must contain an odd number of prime factors of the form $4k+3$ Thus it is divisible by primes not in $A$ of the form $4k+3$. Thus $A$ is not finite.

If $|A|$ is even use the same argument with $P+2$